# Converting shadertoy to Metal (cube mapping ?)

Tags: scenekit, metal

I'am trying to rewrite [this](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltfXDM) shader and i'am stuck with line:

```
float backColor = dot (texture (iChannel0, direction).rgb, channel);
```

how would i do it ? Following [this](https://metalbyexample.com/reflection-and-refraction/) tutorial i should be able to pass my cubetexture here, but i cant wrap my head around this task.
Right now without this line i get some random colors over time so i assume thats part i'am missing.
I'am using SceneKit with SCNProgram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've ported the relevant parts of the shader, loaded a cube map, and bound it as a shader argument, the equivalent line of Metal Shading Language code is simply:

```
float backColor = dot(texCube.sample(cubeSampler, direction).rgb, channel);
```

where `texCube` is of type `texturecube<float, access::sample>` and `cubeSampler` is something like

```
constexpr sampler cubeSampler(coord::normalized, filter::linear, mip_filter::linear)
```

Comment: Can i pass cube map like this: 
`[diamondMaterial setValue:self.scene.background forKey:@"cubeTexture"];`
where self.scene.background is loaded like this:
`self.scene.background.contents = @[@"px.hdr", @"nx.hdr", @"py.hdr", @"ny.hdr", @"pz.hdr", @"nz.hdr"];`
with 6 cube hdrs or should i load it some other way ? I forgot to mention that i'am using SceneKit.

Comment: That might work. You might consider updating your question with this and other such relevant details (such as whether you're using custom techniques, `SCNProgram`, modifiers, etc.) and exactly what effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: my bad, i have updated it - when i supply cubeTexture with scene.background my scene background disappears, but there's no errors. And my current result looks like this http://milionoczu.com/result.jpeg - what can i be missing ?

Comment: Are you saying the background does appear correct when setting its contents as you've shown above? And that it then disappears when reusing that material property with your `SCNProgram`? The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents#2943586) don't seem to indicate that you can use an array of image names to generate a cubemap, but perhaps it works despite being undocumented.

Comment: Also, what sort of geometry are you attaching this material/program to? Is it intended to be drawn as a full-screen quad, some kind of quad-shaped proxy geometry, a mesh shaped like a diamond, or something else?

Comment: currenty i'am loading diamond geometry - but tried with SCNBox and SCNSphere and result is identical - only color changes over time when i move my scene around on ipad

Comment: This is how my conversion looks right now https://gist.github.com/unnamed666/f43823754734f34c8cfbe50388b0a77f
My texturecube is 6 hdr files, loaded from  SCNScene background

Comment: The incoming fragment position is in viewport coordinates, so I think you need to scale it by the render buffer resolution before normalizing: `float2 frag = (2.0 * fragCoord.xy - iResolution.xy) / iResolution.y;` You can calculate the viewport resolution from the scn_frame's `inverseResolution` member.

Comment: good advice, i tried this:
    float2 frag = (2.0 * in.position.xy - scn_frame.viewportSize.xy) / scn_frame.viewportSize.y;
viewportSize is available from iOS 12 and i got some rays visible http://milionoczu.com/result2.jpeg
but why it's so colorful ? scale ?